# String '12/20/2022 12:00:00 AM' was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, datagridview, datetimepicker

[Code & error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ht7wm.png)

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dgvSP.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString(), "dd-MM-YYYY", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
dtpQLSPnsx.Value = dt;
```

Why my datetimepicker value is '12/20/2022 12:00:00 AM' but it show on datagridview only 12/20/2022

I am trying to convert datetimepicker value form '12/20/2022 12:00:00 AM' to '12/20/2022'
and I also try to change format but still didnt work

Comment: Please do not post image of the code that is part of the question, if we were to help, we cannot copy/paste code to test. Also use a [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for future reference.

Comment: Your format specifier doesn't expect a time. It also expects `-` as separators instead of `/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your date is not in the correct format when you are passing it to the `DateTime.ParseExact` method. There is no month with a value of 20. so your date is 20 Dec.

```
var cdate = "12/20/2022 12:00:00 AM";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(cdate, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var date = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: it still didnt work, i think the problem is from my database but i have no clue to fix

Comment: @Adudu123 I would suggest to put breakpoint and debug line by line.